# Sum of Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution

I am aware that the sum of two (or more) normally distributed Random Variables is **not** necessarily also normal.

I do have questions regarding the special case where I have the following addition:

For c $\in \mathbb R$, is c + N(0,a), where I add a normal Random Variable with mean zero and variance a to c, is then the sum normally distributed? Also, does this addition correspond to drawing a random variable X too from a Normal distribution with mean and then add it to N(0,a)?

Hope the question is clear, thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware that the sum of two (or more) normally distributed Random Variables is not necessarily also normal.

Yes, it's usually only the case if they're jointly normal (multivariate normal)

> For c ∈R, is c + N(0,a), where I add a normal Random Variable with mean zero and variance a to c, is then the sum normally distributed?

Yes.

> Also, does this addition correspond to drawing a random variable X too from a Normal distribution with mean and then add it to N(0,a)?

You mean, if $Y\sim N(0,a)$ and $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_x)$? The previous result means that $X+Y|X=c$ is normal. That's useless when you don't condition on the value of $X$, though, and then the form of the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ that you started with again comes in.

Comment: I see. So then c + N(0,a) is normally distributed with N(c,a) - is this correct? What is the conditioning you mention in this case? Not sure I understand that part

Comment: "*So then c + N(0,a) is normally distributed with N(c,a)*"  Yes. The conditioning is conditioning on $X$ taking the value $c$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution; these kinds of ideas are covered in pretty much any basic college level mathematical statistics/probability text.

Comment: I know about conditioned probabilities, but I had never read that sums of random variables can be understood as conditioned probabilities too...did not think that was covered in any basic text.

Comment: Your conclusion that 'sums of random variables can be understood as conditioned probabilities' is ... pretty much a misunderstanding of what was going on. A conclusion based on adding a constant to a random variable carries over to adding two random variables *if one of them is held constant*. That 'holding one constant' is what introduces conditional distributions. If you *don't* hold it constant, the conclusion based on adding a constant *simply doesn't apply*. It's not complicated or mysterious - it's a result of adding constants and attempting to generalize to adding random variables.